# Jolokia OSGi installation stops CXF

Tags: jetty, cxf, apache-karaf, jbossfuse, jolokia

Apache CXF stopped working after the installation of Jolokia osgi bundle installation, when entering the cxf url shows blank page, Please help to overcome this issue. I have installed the jolokia bundle in karaf container.

I'm using jetty version[8.1.14.v20131031] and camel version[2.12.0.redhat-611412]

Comment: do you have a log of what's going on?

Comment: I think this was not working because of version issue, when I degrade the version of jolokia to 1.1.5, cxf have no issues